# Suppose $N\leq H\leq G$, and $N\lhd G$. Prove $H\lhd G\iff H/N\lhd G/N$

Tags: group-theory

Let N be a normal subgroup of $G$ and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. If N
is a subgroup of $H$, prove that $H/N$ is a normal subgroup of $G/N$ iff $H $ is
a normal subgroup of $G$

Comment: **(−1):** You seem to have broken all three of our homework rules. They are: (1) Briefly explain the problem you are trying to solve—do not post your entire assignment verbatim. (2) Explain what you tried and where you're stuck (showing your work is a good idea). (3) Don't ask for complete solutions to the problem—we're not here to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose first that $H\lhd G$. Then for each $g\in G$, $h\in H$ we have that $$ghg^{-1}\in H$$

Then $H/N$ normal in $G/N$ is true if $$(gN)(hN)(g^{-1}N)\in H/N$$ for each $h,g\in G,H$.

But $$(ghg^{-1})N=(gN)(hN)(g^{-1}N)$$ and by normality $ghg^{-1}\in H$ so $(ghg^{-1})N\in H/N$.

Similarily, suppose that for each $h,g$ we have $$(gN)(hN)(g^{-1}N)\in H/N$$ this means  $$(gN)(hN)(g^{-1}N)=(ghg^{-1})N=h'N$$

for some $h'\in H$, so $ghg^{-1}\in H$, and $H\lhd G$.

Comment: In second step ::Isn't it Then $H/N$ normal in $G/N$ is true if $$(gN)(hN)(g^{-1}N)\in H/N$$ for each $h,g\in G,H$.

Comment: @tle Yes, I got my lettrs mixed up. Can you edit it?

Comment: @TLE I fixed it. Did you downvote?

Comment: downvote what??

Comment: @TLE Oh, seems not. My answer, I mean.

Comment: No your earlier vote are 1. Now it's 2.

Comment: @TLE I have $3$ upvotes and $1$ downvote which accounts to a net total of $2$, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Hints (almost complete proof but without explanations):

$$H/N\lhd G/N\iff \forall\;g\in G\,,\,h\in H\;:\;\;(gN)^{-1}(hN)(gH):=(g^{-1}hg)N\in H/N\iff$$

$$\iff g^{-1}hg\in H\iff H\lhd G$$